# Is there a reason why a promise will be undefined on Reactjs build but gets resolved on the localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-redux

I have a react project setup with Redux and Axios. This is a function I am using to get data from an endpoint in my Redux actions:

```
export const getCSEfirstStageApplicants = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(LOADING());

    const response = await axios.get(
      `${baseUrl}/Franchisee/CSEFirstStageApplication`
    );

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const { message, data } = response?.data || {};
      return { message, data };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const { message } = error?.response?.data || {};
    return message;
  } finally {
    dispatch(STOP_LOADING());
  }
};
```

My component looks something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {getCSEfirstStageApplicants} from "../../../redux/user/actions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [cseApplicants, setCseApplicants] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const getFirstStage = async () => {
    const response = await dispatch(getCSEfirstStageApplicants());
    if (response && response.data) {
      console.log(response);
      setCseApplicants(response.data);
      return;
    }
    setCseApplicants([]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFirstStage();
  }, [dispatch]);
}
```

Apparently, this is working fine on my localhost. But when I build the app and push it to the server, it is giving an error on Chrome and Firefox and is working on Edge (browsers I have tested), indicating that response is undefined.

Chrome shows this error:

[image: Image showing error on Chrome]

Firefox shows this error:

[image: Image showing error on Firefox]

At first I thought it was the way the network call was made as preflight seemed to come after the xhr request. But checking Chrome showed that wasn't the error.

Another indication was an error that showed up as asyncgenerator error. I haven't been able to find a relation with this.

Answer (score 0):

add properties to the empty object

```
  const { message, data } = response?.data || {data:[], message:''};
```

Comment: Good day Sachila. I tried this and it actually helped a little. On the component where I am making this API call, I have 5 stages of application. I applied your fix on all of them but only 3 seem to working correctly now